# Is it mandatory to have hibernate.cfg.xml file for configuration

Tags: hibernate, configuration

I do not want to have the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Rather I want to do all the configuration through my code as shown below.

```
private static final SessionFactory factory;
private static final Properties properties;

static
{
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "jhtp7");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

    factory = new Configuration().setProperties(properties).configure().
                            buildSessionFactory();
}
```

I have tried the above approach. But I am facing the problem where hibernate throws an exception saying "`./hibernate.cfg.xml file missing`".

Is it really mandatory to keep the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe it is because of your `configure()` call on the `Configuration` object. Try removing that and hibernate will not look for the non-existent file. Basically you are setting all the required properties via your `properties` object so there is no real need to tell Hibernate to look for a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file which is exactly what the `configure()` method does.

Answer (score 12):

No, I don't think the config xml is mandatory. To fix your problem, I think you need to use the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration class. Have a look at this link: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Basically, you need to things like

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books")
.setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
```

Then to create your sessionFactory, you just say, *cfg.buildSessionFactory();*

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not mandatory to use hibernate.cfg.xml. Just don't use `.configure()`. 
Hibernate will look for hibernate.cfg.xml if we use `.configure()`.

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory ;
    static {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.addAnnotatedClass (org.gradle.Person.class);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate");                                
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");     
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "root");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty(" hibernate.connection.pool_size", "10");

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to log the sql queries on console use:                                                                  configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

Comment: Then how to specify the mapping?

Comment: By this way :                                                      configuration.addAnnotatedClass (org.gradle.Person.class);

Comment: Thanks I did that. I was looking for something like addPackages or addAnnotatedPackages.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are setting all the required properties via your **properties** object so there is no real need to tell Hibernate to look for a hibernate.cfg.xml file which is exactly what the **configure()** method does. it’s not mandatory to use hibernate.cfg.xml. Just don’t use **.configure().**

```
static {
    try {
        Properties prop= new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
        prop.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

        concreteSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
       .addPackage("com.concretepage.persistence")
               .addProperties(prop)
               .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
               .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
```