# Hibernate 5.0.6 Configuration Exception : The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to implement Simple application of Hibernate 5.0.6 in which I'm trying to get the data from the user table and just print on console

I'm facing following exception while invoking the `session.beginTransaction()` method of session object.
I've given all the necessary details required for JDBC Connection in hibernate.cfg.xml

Exception which is rising is as follows:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
    at com.getAWay.rest.HelloWorldService.getUserDetails(HelloWorldService.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using hibernate 5.0.6 version.
Code written in hibernate.cfg.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-/Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuratoin-3.0dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hiberante.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="com.getAWay.entity.UserDetail"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In above code I've provided all the JDBC Configuration properly.
But still facing the problem related to JDBC Connection

My domain Class in which I've mapped all the columns properly to each class variables accordingly
UserDetail Class as follows:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

/**
 * @author Gj
 *
 */

//@Entity
//@Table(name = "user_details", catalog = "test_hibernate", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "phoneNumber") })
public class UserDetail implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -329979543771878237L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public UserDetail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private long userId;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String displayPhoto;
    private Calendar created;
    private Calendar updated;
    private boolean deleted;

    // private boolean isActive;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstName", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "middleName", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastName", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "displayPhoto", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 255)
    public String getDisplayPhoto() {
        return displayPhoto;
    }

    public void setDisplayPhoto(String displayPhoto) {
        this.displayPhoto = displayPhoto;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false) 
    public Calendar getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated", nullable = false)
    public Calendar getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }


    @Type(type = "numeric_boolean")
    @Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        updated = created = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updated = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "[User Id :"+userId+" Ph No :"+phoneNumber+" Name :"+firstName+" "+middleName+" "+lastName
                +" Is Deleted :"+deleted+"]";
    }

}
```

What is missing here? I'm not able to understand. Please help me for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there something wrong in namespaces which are added in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your config:

```
<property name="hiberante.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://lo...
```

Should read:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://lo
```

hiber**an**te vs hiber**na**te. Since that parameter was the connection url Hibernate did not receive any instruction on how to connect to your db, hence the errormessage.

Comment: is there any other way to get the session object without hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: There are different ways depending on your tech-stack and preferences. Check this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8830357/821786 .

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this typo `hiberante` in this line:

```
 <property name="hiberante.connection.url">...
```

With `hibernate` like this:

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">...
```