# Hibernate trying to find hibernate.cfg.xml when configured by spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have configured Hibernate(5.2.6) via spring(4.3.5) But when I run my Junit(4.12) tests it gives out an error saying that it could not locate hibernate.cfg.xml file. Can anyone help me out?

After I run the Junit test, tables are created in database but data is not added, I can see the sql queries being run as I have enables show_sql

[image]

Comment: Can you share the directory structure indicating the location of this file?

Comment: @user2004685 Added

Comment: I can't see your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in here! If you are calling the `configure()` method on your `Configuration ` then you need to have this file. See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830357/is-it-mandatory-to-have-hibernate-cfg-xml-file-for-configuration

Answer (score 0):

did you specify hibernate configured xml file name in web.xml.?
if not specify name of xml file in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:hibernateContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

How is applicationContext is configured for spring and hibernate integration?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:properties/jdbc.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation">    
          <value>classpath:hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>     
    </bean>
```